# Slow import excel file from other folder

Tags: r, readxl

When I import big file excel from different folder where i have my project is more slow to create my new dataframe.

Example on the same file in the project folder and in the other folder. A is create in few seconds B in more minuts.

```
Library(readxl)

A <- read_xlsx (“file1.xlsx”, sheet =1)
B<- read_xlsx (“c://user/utente/Analysis/perf/file1.xlsx”, sheet=1)
```

There is a method to improve?

Comment: I can think of no reason why this could be happening. Are you certain it is the same file? For instance, does `normalizePath("file1.xlsx")` show the same path as you list in `B`? (Also, please don't copy/paste code from Word or something else, as this contains both syntax errors (`Library`) and non-standard quotes (that fail for me). Is `sgretola=` the same thing as `sheet=`? I don't find it in the source, so perhaps that's causing a problem.)

Comment: Sorry i change code with sheet. Yes is the same. I change path because in the other is more slow import file. When is in other folder is an example.

Comment: Okay, you addressed one of my concerns, your code is still a syntax error. Regardless, though, since it is the same exact file in both and you get *significantly* different load times, my guess is that you'll have to open an issue with the package maintainers with a reproducible example (i.e., an actual file uploaded as an artifact with clear directions on how to reproduce it): https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues